# How can i resize MKMapView in a UISheetPresentationController (iOS 15)?

Tags: swift, uikit, mkmapview, ios15

in my UIKit App, i have a DetailViewController with a MKMapView like this:

```swift
class EventViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let viewModel: EventViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: EventViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private lazy var mapView = MKMapView().with {
        $0.isZoomEnabled = true
        $0.isScrollEnabled = true
        $0.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: viewModel.event.structuredLocation!.geoLocation!.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)), animated: true)
        $0.addAnnotation(MKPointAnnotation().with {
            $0.coordinate = viewModel.event.structuredLocation!.geoLocation!.coordinate
        })
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.title = viewModel.event.title
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.with {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            $0.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            $0.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        }
    }  
}
```

And i want to present this DetailViewController in the new UISheetPresentationController like this:

```swift
func showEventDetails(for event: EKEvent) {
    let viewModel = EventViewModel(event: event, baseCoordinator: self)
    let eventViewController = EventViewController(viewModel: viewModel)

    eventViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
    if let sheet = eventViewController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
        sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = true
        sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
    }
    navigationController.present(eventViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Nothing special, but when i want to resize the sheet, from `medium()` to `large()`, the animation is not smooth, because the Map will be redrawn. How can i improve this? I don't wan't to set a constant height to the Map. I want to use a relative height, so you get a bigger map in `large()` size.

How can i resize the MapView smooth when resizing the sheet? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the map view actually being resized as expected?